# Using nested align* to split a long numerator into multiple lines leads to "Erroneous nesting" error

Tags: align, nesting, split

I am using an `align*` environment within another `align*` environment because I have a fraction with a long numerator that I want to split into two lines within the numerator. Here is what I tried:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    f(x)
        & = \frac{
                \begin{align*}
                    ab & - cd + \\
                    ef & - gh
                \end{align*}
            }{z} \\
        & = \dots % I will write more steps here.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

In the example above, the numerator does not seem all that long. It's just `ab - cd + ef - gh` but that's so because I wanted to write a minimal example. Just imagine that this numerator is very long and may occupy two or three lines in reality.

The error I get for the code above is:

```
! Package amsmath Error: Erroneous nesting of equation structures;
(amsmath)                trying to recover with `aligned'.
```

What's the problem? Is nesting `align*` within `align*` not allowed? What is a good way to split a long line of numerator within a fraction?

Comment: align is a top level environment that _starts_ display math like `equation` it shouldn't be nested in any math.  use the `aligned` environment for blocks to be embedded in a larger math expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    f(x)
        & = \frac{
                \begin{aligned}
                    ab & - cd + \\
                    ef & - gh
                \end{aligned}
            }{z} \\
        & = \dots % I will write more steps here.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

You can nest `aligned` with `align(*)`.

Answer (score 2):

Another, simpler, possibility, if  you don't need alignment in the numerator (or denominator) uses the `\splitfrac` command from `mathtools` – the result looks like `multlined`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    f(x) & = \frac{\splitfrac{ ab - cd}{+ ef - gh }}{\splitfrac{x+y}{ + z + t}} \\
        & = \dotsm
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]